# Game for 2 players

Tags: recommendations

Looking for a good board game for 2 players. We currently have Flux, Killer Bunnies, Settlers of Catan, but these are most fun with 4 to 6 players.

Comment: Hey Rob!  Welcome to B&CG.  I am very sorry that I have had to close your question.  We have a [strict policy](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/663/game-recommendation-questions-are-banned) against recommendation questions here.  We've found that these questions don't work very well with the StackExchange format. I hope you'll stick around, we handle rules and strategy questions about specific games very well.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot !

If you are into pure strategy (like chess, you know)… You have:

- Chess (duh)
- Gipf project (6 games with similar strategies but not quite the same).
- Lots of games by Gigamic, like Quoridor, Quixo, Quarto, …
- A whole lot more of games! Most of strategy games are for 2 players.

If you are willing to play on a more hasardeous and/or communication and/or second-guessing games:

- Mr Jack, where one has to find who is the bad guy and the other one tries to make that bad guy escape from the board (and eventually from the table ;-P)
- Kahuna, where each player creates bridges between islands, each majority wins the island, the player with the most islands win.
- Forbidden Island, a cooperative game for 2-4 players, where a team tries to get all the statues off an Atlantis island before it dives into the abbyss.
- War of the Ring, a very complex and long game where the evil and good forces of Middle-Earth fight for the victory. I personnally developped some skills in explaining the rules, it now takes only 2h30 for me to do so. Just saying.
- Even a lot more…

There are a bunch of games for 2 players, as you can see. I suggest that you precise what kind of game you like, so I can tell you more about a cretain category of 2 players game.